# How to Parse a xml and display it in the WebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml

I have an Application which contains only WebView, i need to parse a XML file and display it in the WebView . How can i do that ?

Comment: What you have tried till now and where you are stuck?? Have you checked the faq before questioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this , [How to parse XML in Objective c](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) using ASIHTTPRequest and handle all this methods

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

See this [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) too

This all are beginners guide...

Answer (score 0):

Follow Marvin's suggestion to parse xml,
now if you want to display string on webview, then you can use-

```
 [myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com"]];
```